# How to set cardStack style in react-navigation StackNavigator from screen component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to create an animated effect of revealing a side menu behind a react-navigation StackNavigator.

In looking at the [StackNavigator docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack), and I can see how I can set the cardStyle in the StackNavigator Config options.

This works and gives me the effect I want:

[image]

But this is setting the cardStyle statically for the entire StackNavigator when it is created. I'm looking for a way to programmatically change the cardStack style from within a given screen.

Can anyone suggest a way to make this work?

Comment: Don't set this inside react navigation. Use the Animated library built into react native on the actual view that your stack nav renders. Make it so it animates in on componentDidMount

Comment: @zackify so that's something I have tried, but the issue I run into is that the styling is applied to the screen within the Navigation bar, but it does not include the nav bar as desired in my usecase.

Comment: You can hide the navigation bar in the options for stack nav